# How to verify a write-back 4-way set-associative cache in assembly?

Tags: caching, assembly, cpu-architecture

I've come across this question on glassdoor but I couldn't find any solution with actual assembly or C code to solve it. Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: The question doesn't seem to have an answer without more details.  Was there anything more to go with it?  Keep in mind though that interview questions or questions posted on glassdoor don't always make sense.  Caching should be transparent from the perspective of either C or assembly.

Comment: Hi Aaron, there was no other detail with the question. Only one answer posted with no actual code: "Check for eviction, perform 5 stores in the same set from different memory addresses, see if the 5th store is a hit/miss." [link](http://www.glassdoor.com/Interview/How-would-you-verify-a-write-back-4-way-set-associative-cache-using-assembly-language-programming-QTN_256575.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough cred' to comment so...  By "verify" are you asking to simply confirm that the described parameters are those of a specific cache?  Or is this something more like making sure that what you think is in there is in there?  Or are you trying to figure out what the actual size of the cache is as well?

The easiest thing for the first and third options is to write a doubly nested loop.  The inner loop writes five consecutive bytes one at a time, over and over.  The outer loop changes the stride between the five bytes, doubling the distance each iteration of the outer loop.  Put RDTSCs/0x0f 0x31 (for intel) around the inner loop.  The time will jump materially at some point.  The distance between bytes*4, before the jump in latency, is the size of the cache.  The inner loop should have a trip count of 1000 or so to amortize the initial miss of each cacheline.  The jump in latency likely won't be "huge" due to a second level cache but you should be able to see where the fifth write causes the eviction of the first write.
I suppose you could do 8 writes in the inner loop if you wanted to and that would likely increase the magnitude of the increased latency.